# Integrating the Skype Web Control into your own website

Tags: skype, skypedeveloper

I'm recently trying to integrate the Microsoft Skype ([Skype Web Control](https://dev.skype.com/webcontrol)) into my own website. ([See demo here](http://skype.jackzc.com))

It's quite simple actually, use the 'Web Control Generator' you will get the code, and then put them into a pure HTML file, it's done! Just like this:

```html
<span class="skype-button bubble" data-contact-id="my-skype-id"></span>
<script src="https://swc.cdn.skype.com/sdk/v1/sdk.min.js"></script>
```

It's very simple! you clicked on the 'Bule Bubble' on the bottom right corner of the screen, Skype window popups up, you sign in with your Skype account and then you're good to go!

Chat is ok, you can send messages, even files(didn't try it)! But every time I click on the Video call button which I marked on the attached image, the error message popup up! [image]

It spent me days, asking for Skype support team, googling around and got nothing, PLEASE, any ideas, suggestions will be greatly appreciated!

UPDATE:

1. My testing environment already install a Skype application [Skype 12.1807.264.0]
2. The testing browser is Chrome [Version 64.0.3282.186 (Official Build) (64-bit)]

UPDATE:
  I already put an SSL Certificate (https://) on my testing environment, doesn't work either.

Comment: Anyone? Anything?

Answer (score 0):

All calls must be facilitated through HTTPS. This is a security guideline that needs to be enforced for using Skype Web Control. As told Here https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder/issues/4044

Comment: Thanks for the tips, I already knew this SSL Certificate rule on Skype Web Control since the PM(Skype Web Control team)Brene mentioned in the article above. any other ideas?